# Weird error on iOS

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I have the following lines of code:

```
NSLog(@"deleted row");
if(contacts == nil) {
    NSLog(@"contacts is nil");
}
NSLog(@"hi");
NSLog(@"contacts is %@",contacts);
```

In the console, I see `deleted row` printed, and then I see `hi` printed, and then it crashes. The variable `contacts` is an `NSMutableArray`. If it is not `nil`, why can't I print it out? Why does the program crash?

Comment: if you eliminate the last NSLog does it crash? how do you alloc/initialize the NSMutableArray

Comment: can you show the code where you allocate the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem probably is that your `contacts` instance was deallocated ( e.g. was created as autoreleased outside of current scope and was not retained), so attempting to send it a message (logging variable results in sending it `-description` or `-localizedDescription` message) leads to `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

Simply compare iVar to nil does not need any method calls so even invalid pointer can be used in it.

Comment: even if I retain the nsmutablearray when I alloc and init it (in the viewDidLoad method), it crashes

Comment: May be post the code where you do that? The error most likely is there